# Java Data Types Questions

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int j = + -1234;
    System.out.printf("%d", j);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(j);
  }
}
```

The Result is -1234.
Can any body explain me why the result is -1234 is coming?

Comment: Hm, everything correct. What are you expected?

Comment: this is the same as `0 + (-1234)`

Comment: Bcz the value of - is higher than + so it assign - sign and thats why your answer is -1234

Answer (score 1):

The assigment `int j = + -1234`; is equivalent to:

j = (1) * (-1) * 1234     (a)

now:

-1 = (1) * (-1)          (b)

so substitute b into a and get:

j= -1 * 1234

so j = -1234

In the assignment equation [the + and - are acting as unary oprators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the java compiler take +- as +*- so it results to -1234. if you try -+-1234 then it will processed as -*+*-1234 which is 1234.

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
         int j = -+ -1234;
         System.out.printf("%d", j);
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println(j);
```

}
}

This will print 1234. you cannot use ++/-- since it is already predefined in java for increment and decrement operation